# En un contexto de expresiones regulares, ¿cómo se puede traducir "match"?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, vocabulario-técnico, español-neutral, informática

Estoy traduciendo una respuesta mía de Stack Overflow en la que en un momento dado digo:

> `/PAT1/` matches lines having this text.

Lo que quiero decir es que en un contexto de expresiones regulares, identifico `/PAT1/` como aquella expresión que se cumple si una línea dada contiene el texto "PAT1".

En inglés el verbo que se usa es siempre "match", tanto como verbo (esta línea *matches* este patrón) como como sustantivo (esta línea tiene un *match*). Sin embargo, tengo serias dudas sobre cómo traducirlo al castellano.

[Me han sugerido](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/36028394#36028394):

- coincidir
- emparejar
- empatar

La primera de ellas me gusta bastante, pero sigo dudando de si hay alguna aproximación más estándar. ¿Se os ocurre alguna? Idealmente, que sea entendible en ambos lados del Atlántico.

Comment: Los chilenos decimos "calzar".

Comment: Calzar me gusta. Match En este contexto efectivamente significa *hallar o avisar de lo que siguiere un tal patrón o modelo*. Así que puede haber otros verbos del tipo, pues, hallar, encontrar, marcar, identificar, o incluso paralelizar, alinear, semblar

Comment: Calzar o matchear (no para documentacion, pero para explicar...)

Comment: El manual de PHP en castellano usa *coincidir* http://php.net/manual/es/function.preg-grep.php. Yo uso *matchear*, por supuesto :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Veo que se buscan *referencias sobre el uso en documentación técnica*; entiendo que de "autoridades" en el tema.
Personalmente, en 15 años que llevo programando, siempre he usado y visto usar "**coincidir**" / "**coincidencia**", pero yo no soy una autoridad (todavía :D). Sí lo son en cambio las siguientes:

- En la (lamentablemente poca) [documentación que ofrece **Oracle** en castellano](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/es/articles/sql/expresiones-regulares-base-de-datos-1569340-esa.html), se utiliza ***coincidir*** para el verbo, y ***coincidencia*** para el sustantivo. El término *ocurrencia* se usa solamente para hablar de las apariciones individuales de los caracteres (o grupos) dentro del segmento que se está analizando:

  > **El metacaracter suma `(+)`**
  >
  > El metacaracter suma **coincide** con una o más *ocurrencias* de la subexpresión que lo precede. Por ejemplo, analicemos la expresión regular
  >
  > `cas+a`
  >
  > Para que una cadena de caracteres **coincida** con dicho patrón:
  >
  > - Debe estar el carácter '`c`'
  > - Le debe seguir el carácter '`a`'
  > - Le debe seguir una o mas *ocurrencias* del carácter '`s`'
  > - Le debe seguir el carácter '`a`'
  >
  > Vemos nuevamente tres literales y el metacaracter Suma. Busquemos el patrón en las siguientes cadenas y veamos las **coincidencias**.
- En la [documentación que ofrece **IBM**](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/es/SSJMXE_8.1.0/com.ibm.rational.test.ft.doc/topics/RegExExamples.html) sobre uso de expresiones regulares en sus sistemas, se usan igualmente los términos ***coincidir*** y ***coincidencia***:

  > **Conjunto alfanumérico**
  >
  > Formulario[A-G]
  >
  > Se puede especificar un intervalo de letras contiguas. En esta sintaxis, **coincidirán** "FormularioA", "FormularioB", "FormularioC", "FormularioD", "FormularioE", "FormularioF" y "FormularioG", pero no lo harán "FormularioH" o "FormularioM". El intervalo alfanumérico distingue entre mayúsculas y minúsculas. "Formularioa" no dará ninguna **coincidencia**. Utilice esta sintaxis para que **coincidan** letras mayúsculas y minúsculas en este intervalo: "Formulario[a-gA-G]". Para que **coincida** con cualquier letra del alfabeto estándar, utilice todos los intervalos en mayúsculas y minúsculas: "Formulario[a-zA-Z]".
- La [documentación de **Mozilla Developer Network (MDN)**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) utiliza los mismos términos:

  > #### Utilizando patrones simples
  >
  > Los patrones simples se construyen con caracteres para los que se desea una **coincidencia** exacta. Por ejemplo, el patrón /abc/ **coincidirá** sólo con esta exacta secuencia y orden de caracteres ('abc'). Tal expresión tendría resultados en las cadenas "Hi, do you know your abc's?" y "The latest airplane designs evolved from slabcraft." En ambos existe una **coincidencia** exacta con la subcadena 'abc'. No hay **coincidencia** en la cadena 'Grab crab' debido a que, a pesar de que contiene los caracteres 'a', 'b' y 'c', la sequencia 'abc' nunca aparece.
- Idem para la [documentación de **Microsoft (MSDN)**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) sobre el tema:

  > `(?( name ) Si |no)`
  >   **Coincide** con *sí* si *nombre*, un grupo de captura con nombre o numerado, tiene una **coincidencia**; de lo contrario, **coincide** con la parte opcional *no*.

Creo que, en general, esos son los términos más utilizados en español, ya sea en documentación oficial o en tutoriales de andar por casa.

Answer (score 11):

*Coincidir* me parece perfectamente entendible, y más todavía dado el contexto. Y *coincidencia* para el sustantivo, aunque también he visto *ocurrencia*. El uso común en español parece ser ése al menos (no incluyo ejemplos porque hay tutoriales sobre uso de expresiones regulares en diferentes lenguajes de programación *a patadas* por toda internet).

Entre compañeros informáticos suelo escuchar el verbo *matchear* y (hablando de grandes tareas de filtrado) *hacer un matcheo*, pero no creo que sea conveniente ni necesaria esa informalidad en SE.

Jamás he visto *emparejar* ni mucho menos *empatar* en este contexto y no me imagino que puedan sonar bien.

Comment: ["Ocurrencia"](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Qu7nMUN) es, además, un falso amigo, ya que no significa en español lo mismo que el inglés _occurrence_.

Comment: @JMVanPelt En realidad significa casi lo mismo. Pero tanto en inglés como en castellano a los significados habituales se les suma uno más técnico que no aparece específicamente en los diccionarios.

Comment: ¿Podrías poner cómo traducirías la frase de la pregunta haciendo uso del verbo coincidir?

Answer (score 7):

Concordar/concordancia:

> La expresión regular **seri[oa]** concuerda con las palabras "serio" y "seria".

> No se encontró ninguna concordancia con la expresión regular en el texto.

Aunque no se refiere específicamente a expresiones regulares, usada en [Sobre las opciones de concordancia con palabras clave](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/2497836?hl=es).

En el caso concreto de la pregunta:

> La expresión regular /PAT1/ concuerda con las líneas que contienen este texto.

Más ejemplos:

[Google elimina la Concordancia exacta y de Frase en Adwords](http://www.activalaweb.com/google-elimina-la-concordancia-exacta-y-de-frase-en-adwords/)

[La Poderosa Concordancia Amplia Modificada](https://yopagoporclick.com/concordancia-amplia-modificada/):

> La concordancia amplia modificada o "broad modified match" permite tener palabras clave con mayor alcance que la concordancia de frase y con mayor control que la concordancia amplia.

Comment: Interesante aportación, Martín-Blas. Dada la definición de [_concordar_](http://dle.rae.es/?id=A9wE8sm) en la RAE, se me ocurre que tal vez sería más apropiado decir _No se encontró ninguna concordancia CON la expresión regular en el texto_.

Comment: @fedorqui, editado de acuerdo con la sugerencia. Lo gracioso es que no tengo ni idea de por qué puse "de" habiendo usado "con" en los otros dos ejemplos.

Answer (score 6):

¿Qué tal ***[encajar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=EwwHYTQ)***? Según el diccionario significa "meter algo dentro de otra cosa", "ajustar algo con otra cosa", "corresponder con su totalidad", o "coincidir". Podrías decir, usando su acepción como verbo transitivo:

> La expresión regular `/PAT1/` encaja las líneas que contienen este texto.

Es decir, la expresión regular mete dentro de otra cosa (un listado de coincidencias, por ejemplo) las líneas que contienen ese texto. A fin de cuentas, la etimología es *en* + *caja*, siendo la caja en este caso la expresión regular.

Otra opción podría ser ***[cuadrar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=BPRtMNE)***:

> 10. intr. Dicho de una cosa: Conformarse o ajustarse con otra.

En el caso de tu ejemplo:

> La expresión regular `/PAT1/` cuadra con las líneas que contienen este texto.

Hasta aquí las alternativas, pero la verdad es que [*coincido* con @pablodf76](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/20114/12637) en que el verbo más usado en la documentación es ***[coincidir](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9hq0f9s)***, como se ve en sus acepciones 1 y 3:

> 1. intr. Dicho de una cosa: Convenir con otra, ser conforme con ella.
>   3. intr. Dicho de una cosa: Ajustarse con otra, confundirse con ella, ya por superposición, ya por otro medio cualquiera.

Ejemplos de este uso lo podemos ver, por ejemplo, en la documentación sobre C# en la web de la MSDN. En el artículo sobre `Regex.Match()` traducido manualmente en la versión de Visual Studio 2010, [podemos leer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/twcw2f1c(v=vs.100).aspx) (negritas mías tanto aquí como en los textos siguientes):

> This method returns the first substring in *input* that **matches** the regular expression pattern. You can retrieve subsequent **matches** by repeatedly calling the returned `Match` object's `Match.NextMatch` method. You can also retrieve all **matches** in a single method call by calling the `Regex.Matches(String)` method.

Que se tradujo por:

> Este método devuelve la primera subcadena de *input* que **coincide** con el modelo de expresión regular. Para recuperar las **coincidencias** subsiguientes, llame repetidas veces al método `Match.NextMatch` del objeto `Match` devuelto. También puede recuperar todas las **coincidencias** con una única llamada al método `Regex.Matches(String)`.

Digo "manualmente" porque algunos artículos (sobre todo los de las versiones más recientes) se traducen de forma automática.

Se usa también en la Mozilla Developer Network para describir [el uso de las expresiones regulares](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions):

> Los patrones simples se construyen con caracteres para los que se desea una **coincidencia** exacta. Por ejemplo, el patrón /abc/ **coincidirá** sólo con esta exacta secuencia y orden de caracteres ('abc'). Tal expresión tendría resultados en las cadenas "Hi, do you know your abc's?" y "The latest airplane designs evolved from slabcraft." En ambos existe una **coincidencia** exacta con la subcadena 'abc'. No hay **coincidencia** en la cadena 'Grab crab' debido a que, a pesar de que contiene los caracteres 'a', 'b' y 'c', la sequencia 'abc' nunca aparece.

La gente la usa también en Stack Overflow para preguntar:

> [Expresión regular que **coincida** también con mayúsculas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/50119)

Y Google [también la usa](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1371417?hl=es):

> - **Coincidencia** solo con la frase exacta
> - **Coincidencia** con la palabra o con la frase de una lista
> - **Coincidencia** de una palabra con distintas grafías o con caracteres especiales
> - **Coincidencia** con cualquier dirección de correo electrónico de un determinado dominio
> - **Coincidencia** con cualquier dirección IP de un intervalo de direcciones
> - **Coincidencia** con un formato alfanumérico

Otra alternativa que veo a veces es ***[corresponderse](http://dle.rae.es/?id=AyxqUHu)***:

> 3. intr. Dicho de una cosa: Tener proporción con otra. U. t. c. prnl.
>   4. intr. Dicho de un elemento de un conjunto, colección, serie o sistema: Tener relación, realmente existente o convencionalmente establecida, con un elemento de otro.

Como se ve en la Wikipedia, por ejemplo:

> Una barra vertical separa las alternativas. Por ejemplo, "marrón|castaño" **se corresponde** con *marrón* o *castaño*.

Y en algunos otros sitios como [comentarios en entradas de blogs](https://jmalmellones.wordpress.com/2011/01/06/expresiones-regulares-en-java/):

> ```
> // y vemos si hay correspondencia con el patrón
> boolean emailValido= m.matches();
> ```

Resumiendo: parece que ***coincidir*** y ***coincidencia*** son la opción más usada, seguida de ***corresponderse*** y ***correspondencia***.

Comment: Lo de _encajar_ me parece buena idea. Me suena algo mejor decir _La expresión regular `/PAT1/` encaja CON las líneas que contienen este texto_. Es decir, la analogía con "meter dentro de otra cosa" me cuesta de ver y la veo más en su aspecto de paralelismo entre el patrón y el texto.

Comment: @fedorqui pues sí, lo malo es que me entraba la duda de decir si las líneas encajan con la expresión regular, o si es la expresión regular la que encaja con las líneas.

Comment: Carlos: de tanto decirlo en inglés ya no se me ocurre otra cosa que decir _matches_ jaja. Dado que la expresión regular es un subconjunto, o como mucho el conjunto, de la línea en cuestión, creo que lo apropiado sería decir que _la expresion regular encaja... EN la línea_. Nótese que ahora parecería más correcto utilizar la preposición _en_ que _con_.

Comment: @fedorqui he ampliado mi respuesta con múltiples referencias para así ser digno de tu recompensa y optar a la misma. :-)

Comment: Uau, menudo _bump_ le diste a la respuesta. Siempre das motivos para darte recompensas. Veamos qué más se aporta por aquí y al final de los siete días decido. De momento, me gusta ver que existe coincidencia en utilizar... _coincidencia_. Es bueno porque también permite usar coincidir/coincidencia para emular el uso de _match_ (verbo/sustantivo).

Answer (score 3):

En este contexto lo que hace /PAT1/ es filtrar las líneas quedándose solo con aquellas que contienen el texto PAT1

No se me ocurre ningún verbo que signifique "filtrar y quedarse solo con". Por lo que yo lo traduciría de la siguiente forma aunque quede algo más largo :

> `/PAT1/` filtra las líneas quedándose con aquellas que contienen el parámetro PAT1.

En este caso considero más importante la claridad de la traducción aún a costa de alargar algo el texto.

Comment: El efecto real es el de **"filtrar"** las lineas que cumplen con la RegExp. Me quedo con esta respuesta.

Comment: Nótese que abrí una recompensa para ver si se pueden aportar referencias oficiales. ¡Gracias por tu tiempo!